# how to stretch a UL across the browser window

Tags: html, css, dropdown, background-color

I have an UL that acts as my navigation bar on my web page. currently it is all the way to the left of the screen. I would like it to be centered and have the background color stretch all the way to the left and right, Like below. what would I need to change to stretch the UL across the page like the top example image? [image: Ideal Nav bar]

Here is what it looks like currently:
[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #1D3567;
}

.parent a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.parent:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  display: none;
}

.child li {
  background-color: #1D3567;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: #CCC 1px solid;
  border-right: #CCC 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.child li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 15em;
}

ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #95B4CA;
}

.parent li:hover {
  background-color: #95B4CA;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_ul">
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="https:">Outlook Web</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Production</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class="parent"><a href="">Hennig South</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="">Hennig Enclosure Systems</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="">Hennig South</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="http://">Factory Andon</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="http://">Web Docs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">IT</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="http:/">Knowledge Base</a></li>
      <li><a href="http:/">Submit a Ticket</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="http:/">Archived Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Office Directories</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="http:">Hennig</a></li>
      <li><a href="http:">AME</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="http:">Hennig Parts</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="http">Factory Andon</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="https">Business Cards</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Reports</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">Global Shop<span class="expand">&raquo;</span></a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="inventoryl">Inventory Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="sales">Sales Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="quotesl">Quotes Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="workOrder">Work Order Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="prtUsed">Part Where Used Report</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">Ndustrios<span class="expand">&raquo;</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `ul` a flex container in which you align the children centered, and apply the `background-color` to this element instead of the `li` children by adding this rule:

```
#nav_ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #1D3567;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #1D3567;
}

.parent a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.parent:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  display: none;
}

.child li {
  line-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: #CCC 1px solid;
  border-right: #CCC 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.child li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 15em;
}

#nav_ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #1D3567;
}

ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #95B4CA;
}

.parent li:hover {
  background-color: #95B4CA;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_ul">
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="https:">Outlook Web</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Production</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class="parent"><a href="">Hennig South</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="">Hennig Enclosure Systems</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="">Hennig South</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="http://">Factory Andon</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="http://">Web Docs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">IT</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="http:/">Knowledge Base</a></li>
      <li><a href="http:/">Submit a Ticket</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="http:/">Archived Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Office Directories</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="http:">Hennig</a></li>
      <li><a href="http:">AME</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="http:">Hennig Parts</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="http">Factory Andon</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="https">Business Cards</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Reports</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">Global Shop<span class="expand">&raquo;</span></a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="inventoryl">Inventory Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="sales">Sales Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="quotesl">Quotes Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="workOrder">Work Order Report</a></li>
          <li><a href="prtUsed">Part Where Used Report</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">Ndustrios<span class="expand">&raquo;</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. 1 more quick question (i hope), is there anyway to make the background color of the UL wider ? If you look at my screenshots, the blue background in the first is about double the width of the 2nd screenshot. I hope that made sense lol.

Comment: @SkylarP If you click on the "full page" view button in my answer snippet, you can see that the background color *is*  already full width.

Comment: So width was the incorrect word to use. you are correct, it is already at full width of the page. I meant how can I make the height of the UL bigger? between the two screenshots, the first has double the height of the 2nd. is it possible to change the height?

Comment: You can add a `padding`(top and bottom)  to the `ul` to achieve that